# Moving rows between sheets based on cell edit + blank row found by column lookup not full row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on this for a few days and have turned the internet and these forums upside down, but can't find the answer anywhere. I've learned some scripting along the way, but have determined that what I need to do is way beyond my limits. Any help at all or guidance would be SUPER well received!!

I'm setting up an order sheet system for my and my wife's handmade 'business' (project). Essentially I need to move order 1 (columns a-w) from 'ready to ship" when "done" is entered into column X, onto the next blank row on "sent", discounting the formulas in columns w-z.  So when its checking for a blank row, it should only check columns a-w.

This means that once the order info has moved across onto the new sheet, we have extra functionality added in those columns (I hooked it up to send an email apologising, if an order will be late - hope not, but better to be prepared, with our postal service :) )

[Sample sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cUZHWegLFdOao4Jr7OFqKTQpDMhVBn57ir6zWWA4ZVQ/edit#gid=232600953)

I originally learned how to write a 'move row if value added in column x - and learned about triggers and how to call the sheets etc.

Then, because column x, y and z have formulas, I either end up deleting them when I move the whole row - not cool. Or I end up (if i move only columns a- w) having the new (moved) row, showing up in row 9 million, because it sees the formulas as not blank rows. Ive tried editing a 'find row based on column' script, that seemed to work okay, but then i tried to put the two together and thats when it blew up.

Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong here?

```
function lastRowForColumn(sheet, column){
  // Get the last row with data for the whole sheet.
   var ss = spreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet();// this gets you the 
 active spreadsheet in which you are working   
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sent');
   var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
   var data = sheet.getRange(1, "A", numRows).getValues();
   var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Iterate backwards and find first non empty cell
  for(var i = data.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
    if (data[i][0] != null && data[i][0] != ""){
    return i + 1;

     var ss = spreadSheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet();// this gets you the 
      active spreadsheet in which you are working   
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sent');
      var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

        if(s.getName() == "Ready To Send" && r.getColumn() == 25 && 
    r.getValue() == "Sent") {
     var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sent");
   var lastRow = lastRowForColumn();
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet, i, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 10).moveTo(target);
   s.deleteRow(row);
   }
  }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  var col=rg.columnStart; 
  if(name!='Sheet To Send'){return;}
  if(col==24 && e.value=='done') {
    var ss=e.source;
    var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sent');
    var row=rg.rowStart;
    var srg=sh.getRange(row,1,1,23);
    var data=srg.getValues();
    var drg=sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,23);
    drg.setValues(data);
    sh.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use getDisplayValues. That solves both your (formulas aren't blank problem (make sure your formulas display blank when the row is unused) and also the it isn't moving my numbers problem).

Try:

```
moveMe = [];
rowArray = s.getRange(row,1,1,10).getDisplayValues();
moveMe.push(rowArray);
targetSheet.appendRow(moveMe);
s.deleteRow(row);
```

You might have to wrestle the appendRow a bit but it is the cleanest. If it doesn't work as is try skipping the push step and doing

```
targetSheet.appendRow(rowArray);
```

BETTER (edit):

You need to change first your data row to:

```
var data = sheet.getRange(1, "A", numRows).getDisplayValues();
```

and then later you can simply do:

```
targetSheet.appendRow(data[i]);
s.deleteRow(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

This function takes an edit event and checks if the values edited was changed to 'Sent'. It then copies that row into the sent sheet in the same spreadsheet, maintaining the values.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.value != 'Sent') return false; //If not changed to 'Sent' then stop.

  var range = e.range; //get the range the edit occured in.
  if(range.getColumn() != 25) return false;//see if it was column number 25, ie. Column Y

  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() != 'Ready To Send') return false;

  var editedRow = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns()); //Select the row.

  var sent = sheet.getParent().getSheetByName('Sent');
  sent.appendRow(editedRow.getValues()[0]);  //Copy row to Sent sheet.

  sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow()); //Deleted the original row
}
```